# camel substring operation- n characters from end of message body

Tags: spring, apache-camel

This will probably be a layup for most of you, so I apologize in advance.
I am using Apache camel with spring DSL.
My message body has been converted to a string. I want everything from the 9th to 998th character, preferably using a simple expression.  I have tried

```
<transform>
  <simple>${body.substring(8,${body.length}-1)}</simple>
</transform>
```

but Camel doesn't recognize the subtraction. As such, it will try to convert the string `"1045-2"` to an integer, and obviously fail.  Is there a workaround here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use groovy, javascript etc which is more powerful dynamic programming language

```
<groovy>request.body.substring(8, request.body.length-1)</groovy>
```

You need to add camel-groovy as a dependency together with groovy also.

- [Camel Groovy documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/groovy-language.html)

Comment: From the Man himself :) Works great, but I needed to put an empty argument set after length ( a la `request.body.length()`).
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The following code snippet will work.

```
<transform>
  <simple>${body.substring(8,${body.length()-1})}</simple>
</transform>
```